# Pandas Panel apply: getting current index

Tags: pandas

If I call apply() on pandas DataFrame on axis 1 (each row), I get a Series each time. Then I can use Series.name to access the index value for current row.

But for panel, along certain axis I get a DataFrame each time and there is no DataFrame.name, how can I know which index I am at in the function I am applying?

I could use for loop, but I need to use apply for various reasons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pn = pd.Panel(np.arange(27).reshape(3, 3, 3), list('abc'), list('xyz'), list('ijk'))
```

`apply` over a `pd.Panel` by default iterates over 2-D cross section.  That means it's name has to reference the index from both other dimensions.

For example

```
pn.apply(lambda s: type(s))

('a', 'i')
('a', 'j')
('a', 'k')
('b', 'i')
('b', 'j')
('b', 'k')
('c', 'i')
('c', 'j')
('c', 'k')
```

However, you can tell `apply` that you want to iterate over specific axes such that the function that gets applied gets applied to a `pd.DataFrame` with only one index to track.  In this case, you run into the issue you described.

Instead I'd use `pd.Panel.iteritems`.  You can track the `item` name via the `i` variable in the example I gave.

```
for i, df in pn.iteritems():

    print(i, '\n')
    print(df, '\n')

a 

   i  j  k
x  0  1  2
y  3  4  5
z  6  7  8 

b 

    i   j   k
x   9  10  11
y  12  13  14
z  15  16  17 

c 

    i   j   k
x  18  19  20
y  21  22  23
z  24  25  26
```

Comment: Does it iterate over major axis only?

Comment: you only get `iteritems`.  If you want to iterate over another axis, you have to transpose.  `pn.transpose(1, 0, 2).iteritems()`

Answer (score 2):

Actually in the case of a Panel, name still works it just returns a tuple:

```
wp = pd.Panel(np.random.randn(2, 5, 4), items=['Item1', 'Item2'],
                  major_axis=pd.date_range('1/1/2000', periods=5),
                  minor_axis=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
wp.apply(lambda x: print(x.name))
```

x.name in this case yields:

```
('Item1', 'A')
('Item1', 'B')
('Item1', 'C')
('Item1', 'D')
('Item2', 'A')
('Item2', 'B')
('Item2', 'C')
('Item2', 'D')
```

So you can simply unpack the tuple and grab the indices

Comment: Nice solution ! Could you also add an output for `wp.apply(lambda x: print(x.name), axis='minor')` - this will show the difference?

Comment: wp.apply(lambda x: print(type(x)),  axis=[0, 2]) is how I would call lambda, so I actually get a DataFrame each time, not a Series.

Comment: You might want to take a look at the package called xray (http://xray.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). "xarray (formerly xray) is an open source project and Python package that aims to bring the labeled data power of pandas to the physical sciences, by providing N-dimensional variants of the core pandas data structures."  It's set up to more naturally allow you to do what you're trying to do I think, and plays nicely with pandas.